# I have a db2 stored procedure returning 2 values, how do i use this procedure in a select statement?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a DB2 stored procedure (my_proc) that returns two values. I want these two values to be displayed as two different columns.

Is the following correct way to use it?

```sql
select my_proc(parameter1,parameter2,parameter3) as column1,column2;
```

Please guide as I am learning DB2 and new to stored procedure.

Comment: You cannot select from a procedure. Consider using a table-valued function that returns a row; you _can_ select from such a function.

Comment: @mustaccio i already have a running query that uses stored procedure in the following way -
select column_name, my_procedure(....) as mycolumn from table where ....;

but this procedure returns only one value, i want to know how to use the one returning two or more values?

Comment: Things may not be as you think they are.  You can only CALL a stored-procedure in Db2.  You can reference an SQL-function in a SELECT but you cannot directly invoke a stored-procedure in a SELECT.

Comment: You can wrap you stored procedure into a table function, which processes the result set returned by SP and returns the corresponding result set (using so called `pipelined function`). If your SP is declared as `MODIFIES SQL DATA`, then the process is more complex (you need one more intermediate SP), but it's doable as well...

Answer (score 0):

Consider if it is possible or not for you to convert your stored procedure to a UDTF (user defined table function). This can be selected from and joined to and works very similar to a stored procedure.

https://www.itjungle.com/2016/06/14/fhg061416-story03/